# Typescript - create a new class instance based on other class instance

Tags: typescript

Say I have these two classes:

```
class MyTypeOne {
  constructor(
      public one = '',
      public two = '') {}
}

class MyTypeTwo extends MyTypeOne {
  constructor(
      one = '',
      two = '',
      public three = '') {
    super(one, two)
  }
}
```

What's the most concise way to create a `MyTypeTwo` instance based on an existing `MyTypeOne` instance?

Comment: More concise than ```let mt2 = new MyTypeTwo();```?

Comment: `const mt2 = new MyTypeTwo(mt2.one, mt2.two, '"')` or overload the constructor.

Comment: @Wainage that's not based on an existing instance of `MyTypeOne`

Comment: @LppEdd Change ```MyTypeTwo``` constructor to accept an instance of ```MyTypeOne```

Comment: @Wainage I'll have to assign each field. I know that's ok, I was just wondering if there is shorter a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is going to happen somewhere unless you are going to literally grab object keys and loop, which would actually be harder to read and more lines of code... so I'd probably just use a bit of creational patterning!

```
class MyTypeOne {
    constructor(
        public one = '',
        public two = '') { }
}

class MyTypeTwo extends MyTypeOne {
    constructor(
        one = '',
        two = '',
        public three = '') {
        super(one, two)
    }

    static fromMyTypeOne(myTypeOne: MyTypeOne) {
        return new MyTypeTwo(myTypeOne.one, myTypeOne.two);
    }
}

const one = new MyTypeOne('a', 'b');
const two = MyTypeTwo.fromMyTypeOne(one);

console.log(two);
```

## Auto-Map

For completeness, this is the long version that automatically maps the members. It's a different set of trade offs!

```
class MyTypeOne {
    constructor(
        public one = '',
        public two = '') { }
}

class MyTypeTwo extends MyTypeOne {
    constructor(
        one = '',
        two = '',
        public three = '') {
        super(one, two)
    }

    static fromMyTypeOne(myTypeOne: MyTypeOne) {
        const typeTwo = new MyTypeTwo();

        for (let key in myTypeOne) {
            if (myTypeOne.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                typeTwo[key] = myTypeOne[key];
            }
        }

        return typeTwo;
    }
}

const one = new MyTypeOne('a', 'b');
const two = MyTypeTwo.fromMyTypeOne(one);

console.log(two);
```